# How to merge columns to index in pandas pivot-table?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have a dataframe for air pollution for date and time in matches like this:

```
Date            Items      00        01       02        ...       23
2010-01-01      AMB_TEMP   8         10       ...                 15
2010-01-01      CO         10        15       ...                 20
...
2010-01-02      AMB_TEMP   2         5        ...
2010-01-02      CO         5         12       ...
...
2010-01-03      AMB_TEMP   5         25       ...
...
```

I want to aggregate date and time per match, that is, to get dataframe like this:

```
Match            AMB_TEMP  CO   NO  NO2
2010-01-01 00    8         10   ..  ..
2010-01-01 01    10        15   ..  ..
...
2010-01-01 23    15        20   ..  ..
```

I know I can manually stack them, but I was wondering if there's a more efficient way to get it. Now, what I've done is:

```
df.pivot_table(values=df[df.columns[2:]], index='Date', columns='Items')
```

And it returns:

```
              0                            1  
Match         AMB_TEMP  CO   NO  NO2   ... AMB_TEMP  CO   NO  NO2
2010-01-01    8         10   ..  ..    ... 10        15   ..  ..
2010-01-02    2         5    ..  ..    ... 5         12   ..  ..
...
2010-01-07    10        10   ..  ..    ... 10        NA   ..  ..
```

I'm not knowing how to merge date and time to turn them into '2010-01-01 00', '2010-01-01 01', '2010-01-01 02', ...  indexs?

Answer (score 0):

The pandas `melt` function appears to do the job, or at least part of it, and with pivot_table can get all the way.

`melt` does a sort of un-pivot, and if we use it on your '00' through '23' columns, it flips those to being in the rows.

```
df2 = pd.melt(df,id_vars=['Date','Items'],value_vars=df[df.columns[2:]])
```

That line will return this (well, my data is slightly modified from yours)

```
    Date    Items   variable    value
0   2010-01-01  AMB_TEMP    00  8.0
1   2010-01-01  CO  00  10.0
2   2010-01-02  AMB_TEMP    00  2.0
3   2010-01-02  CO  00  5.0
4   2010-01-03  AMB_TEMP    00  5.0
5   2010-01-01  AMB_TEMP    01  10.0
6   2010-01-01  CO  01  15.0
7   2010-01-02  AMB_TEMP    01  5.0
8   2010-01-02  CO  01  12.0
9   2010-01-03  AMB_TEMP    01  25.0
10  2010-01-01  AMB_TEMP    02  15.0
11  2010-01-01  CO  02  20.0
12  2010-01-02  AMB_TEMP    02  NaN
13  2010-01-02  CO  02  NaN
14  2010-01-03  AMB_TEMP    02  NaN
15  2010-01-01  AMB_TEMP    23  NaN
16  2010-01-01  CO  23  NaN
17  2010-01-02  AMB_TEMP    23  NaN
18  2010-01-02  CO  23  NaN
19  2010-01-03  AMB_TEMP    23  NaN
```

The new 'variable' column contains what were previously the column headers, and 'value' contains that old value. Now we can make a new column called 'Datetime' to concat the Date and this new time:

```
df2['Datetime'] = df2['Date'] + ' ' + df2['variable']
```

Now if we run the pivot_table function on this new dataframe, we will get what I think is your goal

```
df3 = df2.pivot_table(values='value',index='Datetime',columns='Items')
        Items   AMB_TEMP    CO
Datetime        
2010-01-01 00   8.0 10.0
2010-01-01 01   10.0    15.0
2010-01-01 02   15.0    20.0
2010-01-02 00   2.0 5.0
2010-01-02 01   5.0 12.0
2010-01-03 00   5.0 NaN
2010-01-03 01   25.0    NaN
```

This does leave those new datetimes as strings, FYI.